# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields - Find numerical average of two fields

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, average, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress.
I have two fields - 'Score One' and 'Score Two' which are text fields that allow the user to input a number.

In addition to showing these fields, I'd like to be able to get an average of the two numbers and show that as well.

For example...

```
<?php the_field('score_one'); ?>
```

Gives me....80

```
<?php the_field('score_two'); ?>
```

Gives me....60

How can I calculate the average of the above two scores on the front end and show that as a third number?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What about (score 1 plus score 2 )/ 2 you can get the php of that I am posting from mobile

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (the_field('score_one') + the_field('score_two')/2 ;
```

pay attention that your value are not null nor something else than integer.